# Structures/Linked Lists/Pointers/Strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, linked-list

So I'm having a bit of trouble with Linked Lists in C. In general, I get the concept and and the algorithm since I have learned the ideas already in Java. But it seems like it's a different story in C, as we also take into consideration memory allocation.

Anyway, I have this code down here:

```
while (curr != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", (*curr).name);
    curr = (*curr).next;
}
```

Where `curr` is a `struct Student` and one of the "attributes" of `Student` is `name`. So suppose I have already added in my nodes to the list. And when I execute the above, I seem to be getting the same names altogether. Below is my code for adding the nodes into the linked list:

```
void insertNode(char *name, int idNum, char sex) {

    struct Student *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct Student));

        //not entirely sure if this is the right way to do it
    if (s == NULL) { 
        printf("Memory allocation failed.");
        return;
     }

    (*s).name = name;
    (*s).idNum = idNum;
    (*s).sex = sex;

    (*s).next = head;        //head is the start of the list
    head = s;         //inserting the node at the beginning of the list

    curr = head;     //place the current pointer at the start of list
}
```

Basically it seems like I have no problems with the `int` and `char`. If I have `{"Alice", 1000, 'F'} -> {"Bob", 1001, 'M'} -> {"Charlie", 1002, 'M'}` in my list, I noticed the last name added to the list, `Alice`, will be the one that's being printed out. So the printout will be:

```
Alice
Alice
Alice
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there something I'm missing? I'm a beginner in C and still learning by myself. Thanks so much for any help and advice!

Comment: You have not presented an [mcve], so we cannot be certain, but the most likely explanation is that you're setting the `name` member of every record to point to the same same array.  When you print the list elements, then, naturally it prints the same name for each element, because they all refer to the same storage.  Instead, when you insert a node, you need to make a copy of the provided name, and assign that to the node.

Comment: Why do you use `(*pointer).field` instead of the more natural `pointer->field`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I just realized my mistake. I'm supposed to use malloc to allocate memory and use the strcpy method to be able to copy the contents of `name`. I forgot that direct assignment doesn't work for strings. Thanks again!

Comment: When making the copy of the original data 'name' you might consider using `strdup()` instead of `malloc()` + `strcpy()`.   Note: before exiting the program, you will still need to pass all those pointers to `free()`

Comment: Most likely, all of your `name` pointers are pointing to the same address.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the head pointer.

Here is the complete working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Student
{
    char * name;
    int idNum;
    char sex;
    struct Student * next;
};

struct Student * head=NULL;

struct Student *
insertNode (char *name, int idNum, char sex)
{

  struct Student *s;
  s = malloc (sizeof (struct Student));

  if (s == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Memory allocation failed.");
      return NULL;
    }

  (*s).name = name;
  (*s).idNum = idNum;
  (*s).sex = sex;


  (*s).next = head;     //head is the start of the list

  head = s;

  return head;          
}


int
main ()
{
    insertNode("Alice", 1, 'F');
    insertNode("Peter", 2, 'M');
    insertNode("Mike", 3, 'M');


  while (head != NULL)
    {
      printf ("%s\n", (*head).name);
      head = (*head).next;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Mike
Peter
Alice
```

However, there are plenty of improvements that can still be done in your code. In particular, the notation `(*s).name` has a shorthand in C and that is `s->name` which is more clean. You can also avoid the global head variable and instead pass its pointer so that its changed value can be maintained in between calls.

Comment: Almost complete. After you print your list, how do you free it? Any of it? How do I print it again?

Comment: Since in the `while` loop inside the while loop the `head` pointer holds `NULL` value at the end, you need to initially store the `head` pointer value into another temp variable and then do the freeing of the linked list - the same way as done in while loop  
 `
struct Student * temp= head;
  while (head != NULL)
    {
      printf ("%s\n", (*head).name);
      head = (*head).next;
    }

    //delete
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        free(head);
    }`

Comment: Yes, yes, and you should explain why all list nodes will print in reverse order. The *insert-at-beginning* linked-list population approach has some significant drawbacks -- unless your intent is to reverse the order of entries (or the list is doubly-linked). It saves iteration on insert, but the list order is sacrificed. (may not be a concern)

Answer (score 1):

`(*s).name = name;` sets the name in the struct to the local variable name which will become invalid at the end of the `insertNode` function.

You need to make a copy of the name.

You can use `s->name = strdup(name);` (Just rememeber you need to free `s->name` when you delete a node.

perhaps a simpler method whice you get your head around C would be to make `name` in the student node an array `char name[32];` or similar. Then you would `strcpy()` into it but have one less thing to free.

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. `name` is a pointer to a variable outside the function. So nothing becomes invalid at the end of the function. The problem is that all elements will end up pointing to the same (valid) object.

Comment: If you use a fixed length array for the `s->name` member then make sure you are careful with lengths. You don't want to try to `strcpy()` a 40 character name into a 32 character array for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear as to the exact source of the problem. The answer by Syed does a good job identifying a solution, but there are some subtleties you need to be aware of as you are learning linked-lists.

First, your assignment of `s->name = name;` will only work if the names are *string literals* where you assign the address to the beginning of a string stored in *read-only* memory to `s->name`.

If you are reading values from a file (or `stdin`) and passing a pointer containing `name` to `insertnode`, then all of your nodes `s->name` will hold the pointer address, which, if it is still in scope will point to the storage containing the *Last Name Read*, and if your pointer used to pass `name` to `insertnode` has gone out of scope, you will invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to access `s->name`.

As correctly noted in the comments, the way to handle the situation is to allocate storage for each `name` passed to `insertnode`, assign the starting address to `s->name` and copy `name` to `s->name`. You can use `strdup` if you have that available, otherwise a simple allocation and `strcpy` is all that is required:

```
    size_t len = strlen (name);     /* get length of name */
    /* allocate/validate storage for name */
    if ((s->name = malloc (len + 1)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc - name");
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (s->name, name);         /*  copy name to s->name */
```

(**note:** since `strdup` allocates memory (e.g. in `s->name = strdup(name);`), you should still validate `s->name` is not `NULL` after the call. Also note that strings is C are terminated with the *nul-characer*, `'\0'`. Therefore, in order to allocate enough storage to hold `name` plus the *nul-terminating* character, you must allocate `strlen (name) + 1` bytes.)

Next, while 100% OK, your *insert-node-before* `head` in a singly-linked list will have the affect of reversing the order of the nodes inserted into your list. While this may not matter for your implementation, it may be surprising to you when you do print the list. This does save iterating to the next free node on insert, but sacrifices input order to do so.

An alternative, would be to insert the nodes in order by simply checking if `head` is `NULL`, and if so, insert the first node, otherwise, iterate until `list->next = NULL` and insert the new node as `list->next`. (this also requires that you initialize all `s->next` nodes `NULL` when you allocate storage for them. A simple implementation (making use of a `typedef` for `struct student` for convenience), would look similar to:

```
/* returns pointer to new node on success, or NULL on failure */
student *insertnode (student **head, char *name, int idnum, char sex)
{
    student *s = malloc (sizeof *s);    /* allocate new node */

    if (s == NULL) {                /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc - s");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* populate new node */
    size_t len = strlen (name);     /* get length of name */
    /* allocate/validate storage for name */
    if ((s->name = malloc (len + 1)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc - name");
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (s->name, name);         /*  copy name to s->name */
    // s->name = name;      /* only works for string literals */
    s->idnum = idnum;
    s->sex = sex;
    s->next = NULL;         /* always initialize ->next NULL */

    if (*head == NULL) {            /* handle add 1st node */
        *head = s;
    }
    else {                          /* handle add rest */
        student *iter = *head;      /* declare pointer to head */
        while (iter->next != NULL)  /* while ->next not null */
            iter = iter->next;      /* get next node */
        iter->next = s;             /* set iter->next to new node */
    }

    return s;   /* head never changes, return current node 
                   to indicate success/failure of insert. */
}
```

Also, you should avoid declaring global variables. There is no reason your list shouldn't be declared in `main()` and a pointer (or address of the pointer if the list address could change) be passed as a parameter to any function that needs to operate on the list. Just move the declaration of `head` inside `main()`, and then add a pointer to pointer to list as a parameter for `insertnode` (as was done above).

You should `free()` all memory you allocate. (yes, this happens at `exit`, but building good habits now of preserving a pointer to the beginning address of all memory you allocate, and freeing that memory when it is no longer needed will pay dividends and your project grow in size.

Finally, when you iterate over your list, you must use a separate pointer. Otherwise, if you iterate using `head`, it is a one-way street. When you iterate until `head == NULL`, you have lost the only reference you had to all the memory you allocated and have no way of getting them back. Simply use a temporary pointer, e.g.

```
    student *iter = head;   /* use separate pointer to iterate list */
    while (iter != NULL) {
        printf ("%-8s  %4d  %c\n", iter->name, iter->idnum, iter->sex);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
```

(of course on your final trip over the list to free all the list memory -- it doesn't matter what you use -- there won't be any more list when you are done)

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {    /* typedef makes declarations easier    */
    struct student *next;   /* pointers 1st limits size to 24-bytes */
    char *name, sex;
    int idnum;
} student;

/* returns pointer to new node on success, or NULL on failure */
student *insertnode (student **head, char *name, int idnum, char sex)
{
    student *s = malloc (sizeof *s);    /* allocate new node */

    if (s == NULL) {                /* validate allocation */
        perror ("malloc - s");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* populate new node */
    size_t len = strlen (name);     /* get length of name */
    /* allocate/validate storage for name */
    if ((s->name = malloc (len + 1)) == NULL) {
        perror ("malloc - name");
        free (s);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy (s->name, name);         /*  copy name to s->name */
    // s->name = name;      /* only works for string literals */
    s->idnum = idnum;
    s->sex = sex;
    s->next = NULL;         /* always initialize ->next NULL */

    if (*head == NULL) {            /* handle add 1st node */
        *head = s;
    }
    else {                          /* handle add rest */
        student *iter = *head;      /* declare pointer to head */
        while (iter->next != NULL)  /* while ->next not null */
            iter = iter->next;      /* get next node */
        iter->next = s;             /* set iter->next to new node */
    }

    return s;   /* head never changes, return current node 
                   to indicate success/failure of insert. */
}

int main (void) {

    student *head = NULL;

    insertnode (&head, "Alice", 1000, 'F');    /* insert nodes */
    insertnode (&head, "Peter", 1001, 'M');
    insertnode (&head, "Mike",  1002, 'M');

    student *iter = head;   /* use separate pointer to iterate list */
    while (iter != NULL) {
        printf ("%-8s  %4d  %c\n", iter->name, iter->idnum, iter->sex);
        iter = iter->next;
    }

    /* free allocated memory */
    while (head != NULL) {  /* freeing list, pointer used doesn't matter */
        student *victim = head;     /* save pointer to node to delete */
        head = head->next;          /* move to next node */
        free (victim->name);        /* free storage for name */
        free (victim);              /* free storage for node */
    }
}
```

(**note:** while not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_head_next
Alice     1000  F
Peter     1001  M
Mike      1002  M
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll_head_next
==30229== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30229== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30229== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30229== Command: ./bin/ll_head_next
==30229==
Alice     1000  F
Peter     1001  M
Mike      1002  M
==30229==
==30229== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30229==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30229==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 89 bytes allocated
==30229==
==30229== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30229==
==30229== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30229== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Comment: Wow, very comprehensive answer! Only thing I'd add is to add a comment to explain that we add one to the string length when performing the malloc (`malloc (len + 1)`) so that there is room for the null terminator character, which isn't counted by `strlen()`.